# WPF RichTextBox.AppendText from another thread

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, richtextbox, .net-core-3.1

I've got a WPF RichTextBox that I'd like to get working as a log output for the app.
I have a static class Log with method to write to the WPF RTB. Of course, this doesnt work when a background thread call the method.

I've tried using BeginInvoke, which works until the app gets closed throwing an error 'System.Windows.Application.Current.get returned null'

What is the proper approach to updating WPF RichText from other threads. And further, I dont think this background thread is disposing properly, any recommendations?

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
  Worker worker = new Worker();
  public MainWindow()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
    Log.rtb_control = rtbLog;  // pass RTB ref to Log
    worker.Start();
  }
}

public static class Log
{
  public static RichTextBox rtb_Control;
  
  public static void Add(string Text)
  {
    App.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
    {
      rtb_Control.AppendText($"{Text}\r");
    }
  }
}

public class Worker
{
  bool _Enabled = false;
  public Worker()
  {
    _Manager = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Thread_Manager));
    _Manager.Start();
  }

  public void Start()
  {
    _Enabled = true;
  }

  void Thread_Manager()
  {
    while(true)
    {
      if(_Enabled) { Log.Add("Inside Thread"); }
      Thread.Sleep(10000);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You don't like `while(true)`.  Ensure the thread is stopped before you allow the window to close.  Google "wpf stop thread on window close", lotsa hits.  Do note that with such long delays, it starts to make a lot more sense to use a timer.

Comment: Thx much, adding a Closing() event seems to have helped close this thread.


`void windowMain_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
    System.Environment.Exit(System.Environment.ExitCode);
}`